# c execv pass arguments through a function

Tags: c, execv

I'm trying to understand this code:

```
char * pl[] = {"test.sh", NULL};
execv("./test.sh", pl);
```

This will execute my script from a c program, but this will not:

```
execv("./test.sh", ["test.sh", NULL]);
```

This delivers an error message:

> error: expected expression before '[' token

This doesn't work either:

```
execv("./test.sh", (char *) ["test.sh", NULL]);
```

Same exact error...

What is going on here?

I am obviously misunderstanding the `char * []` declaration type.  Should I be able to cast the array?  Can i get this into one line of code?

I am not understanding the {}, how would I pass this bit to a function which is the end goal of this code snippet?

Comment: C is not Python — or Perl, or C++, or Java, or C#, or …  If you choose to try notations from other languages in C code, expect them not to work, or to work differently.  You will need to read a book on C to get an understanding of the language and its syntax.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I never mentioned any programming language other than C.  execv wants a `char *const argv[]`, I am asking how to use this in an argument to execv.  "read a book" does not answer this question.  I have read several including ANSI C.  I did not however memorize the whole standard... Mea culpa

Comment: The notation using square brackets around a list of arguments isn't something that a person who only codes in C would come up with.  Some of the languages I mentioned do support such notations, so I inferred that you already knew at least one other language, and that language is not Pascal, Algol, Fotran, COBOL, Basic, Modula-3, ….

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a compound literal:

```
execv("./test.sh", (char*[]){"test.sh", NULL});
```

This is for C99 and later only.